# PHP halting a script and starting it back again

Tags: php

I have a php script in which I have a if-else condition.. I want the script to end processing and start executing back from the top if the condition is not met... example :

```
<?php

$var = 2;

if($var != 1){
stop execution and go to the top and start executing again...
}else{
echo $var; 
}
?>
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Won't that be an infinite loop then ?

Comment: yes i want that to be something like an infinite loop with sleep..

Comment: Rather then a suggested goto statement, I'd just wrap it in a `while(true){ .... continue;...  ... break;....}`  construct.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with the goto statement:
http://php.net/goto

Comment: Or the more scientifically inclined version of Dijkstra: https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/ewd02xx/EWD215.PDF

Comment: @Nanne I know =) But it is implemented and realized in PHP, so shame on Zend :D

Answer (score -1):

If you want a infinite loop, then most simply put a infinite loop ... then break when you want to break

```
<?php
   while(true){
    $var = 2;
    if($var != 1){
        continue;
    }else{
        echo $var; 
                break;
    }
    }
?>
```